# if repository deleted from github, will gradle url works or not?

Tags: android, android-studio

i have complied library in my project,

```
   compile 'com.github.nguyenhoanglam:ImagePicker:1.1.3'
```

if this repository will be deleted after sometime, will it work in my project later ? I mean after the signed apk, app will work ?

if yes then how,
if no then why ?

Comment: Not 100% sure but I would expect it to continue working.  This assumes that the APK ships with the dependency inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your apk will work.

**WHY?**
Your apk contains your project code as well as all library code so, if that project will be removed from github, it doesn't affect your apk behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle once compiled anything from repo then it uses cached strategy , if you remove the repo, gradle still have this lib in local library, but you need to work with gradle offline.

Answer (score 1):

From [Frequently Asked Question](https://jitpack.io/docs/FAQ/)

What happens if a tag or repository is deleted on GitHub?

If the project was already built then JitPack will continue serving the existing artifacts. It will not rebuild the project at the new tag. In case you need to redo a release the best option is to create a new version on GitHub.